# Pulling shipping details from one wordpress plugin into another

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I believe I am close but entirely unsure as my limited php knowledge is based on trial and error. I am trying to pull data from a plugin that creates my shipping label into a plugin that tracks shipping. Specifically Elex EasyPost into Advanced Shipping Tracking.

I have an example snippet for shipstation integration from AST here:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipstation_shipnotify', 'add_tracking_information_into_order', 10, 2  );  
function add_tracking_information_into_order($order, $tracking_details){
    $order_id  = $order->get_id();
    $args = array(
        'tracking_provider'        => $tracking_details['carrier'],
        'tracking_number'          => wc_clean( $tracking_details['tracking_number'] ),
        'date_shipped'             => wc_clean( $tracking_details['ship_date'] ),
        'status_shipped'           => 1,
    );
    $ast = new WC_Advanced_Shipment_Tracking_Actions;
    $tracking_item = $ast->insert_tracking_item( $order_id, $args );
}
```

It should be similar but obviously I need to replace the hook and the items in the array. Here is what Elex sent me when asked for the hooks they are using.

```
get_post_meta($order_id, ‘wf_easypost_labels’);

Sample output:

array(

0=>(‘url’=>label_url,’tracking_number’=> (string)’tracking code’,’integrator_txn_id’=> ‘integerator_id’,’shipment_id’=>’package_shipment_id’,’order_date’=>order_date,’carrier’=>EX:USPS,”link”=>tracking_link,);//First package

1=>(‘url’=>label_url,’tracking_number’=> (string)’tracking code’,’integrator_txn_id’=> ‘integerator_id’,’shipment_id’=>’package_shipment_id’,’order_date’=>order_date,’carrier’=>EX:USPS,”link”=>tracking_link,);//Second package

)
```

So here is my attempt to use their array in my own snippet:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_tracking_information_into_order', 10, 2  );
function add_tracking_information_into_order($order, $myship_func){
    $myship_func = get_post_meta($order_id, 'wf_easypost_labels');
    $order_id  = $order->get_id();
    $args = array(
        'tracking_provider'        => $myship_func['carrier'],
        'tracking_number'          => wc_clean($myship_func['tracking code']),
        'date_shipped'             => wc_clean($myship_func['order_date']),
        'status_shipped'           => 1,
    );
    $ast = new WC_Advanced_Shipment_Tracking_Actions;
    $tracking_item = $ast->insert_tracking_item( $order_id, $args );
}
```

When the order is initially filled and the label is generated Elex grabs all the data from and sticks it in the meta. I need to pull that meta either at the time of generation or post generation and stick it in the AST fields.

My main question is thus - Am I on the right track here? Do I just need to figure out the correct hook or is my method for accessing the Elex array incorrect? Again, I usually compare codes, slice and dice, and get things to "look right" and then they work (or not). I myself don't have too deep of knowledge about arrays or class functions (which I believe the Elex one is).

In this case the code is silently failing so I suspect it is the hook involved or a combination of the hook and my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not going to dissect all the code, but this line `$myship_func = get_post_meta($order_id, 'wf_easypost_labels');` won't do anything if it's outside your function. You need to either pass `$myship_fun` variable to the action hook as an argument, or put it *inside* your function , which is what I would recommend. Put it right after your `$order_id = ...`

Comment: Thank you - edited post.. I posted in the wrong order but issue stands. I appreciate you taking a moment to take a look and thank you for catching that.

Comment: The other thing I noticed, is that your function isn't actually doing anything - there's no `return` statement. Instead of assigning to the `$tracking_item` variable, change that to a `return` statement `return $ast->insert_tracking_item( $order_id, $args);`